# matlab: struct buffer size bigger than 4096?

Tags: matlab, file-io, buffer

I have a matlab script someone else coded and it fails to load a string sequence longer than 4095 (buffer size error). How can I make the element in the `struct` bigger to accommodate bigger string sequences in it? Here is the bit of code that creates the `struct`:

```
    [...]
    seq = struct('Header',{}, 'Sequence', {});
    for ii=1:gene_num
        seq(ii).Header = raw{ii+1,1};
        seq(ii).Sequence = raw{ii+1,2};
    end;
    [...]
```

Here is the error:

```
^G??? Buffer overflow (bufsize = 4095) while reading string from
file (row 54660, field 1). Use 'bufsize' option. See HELP TEXTREAD.

Error in ==> textread at 177
[varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:});

Error in ==> fastaread at 101
    ftext = textread(filename,'%s','delimiter','\n');

Error in ==> tfbs_scanner_zscore at 8
S = fastaread(fin);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What precisely does the error say, and on what line does it occur?

Comment: So you did, as suggested, type `help textread` and you read the help text and found the 'bufsize' parameter and then you did what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are trying to read contains lines longer than the default buffer size used in the TEXTREAD function.

Try increasing the buffer size:

```
ftext = textread(filename, '%s', 'delimiter','\n', 'bufsize',50000);
```

choose a value that works for you

By the way, TEXTREAD is now obsolete, consider upgrading to TEXTSCAN